# Run tests before dependency resolution

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have a root level project which contains ~100 sub-projects. The main goal of root project is to collect all produced jars into installer.

In main project I am including subproject as a dependency and then do installer compilation like this:

```
dependencies {
  blahblah project(":subproject1")
}

task blah(type: Copy) {
  from(configurations.blahblah)
  into 'qwe'
}

//and so on
```

I understand that jar artifact is produced by `jar` task and this task doesn't depend on `test` task. And I see situation when Gradle produces installer first (which is time consuming) and only then runs tests. This is not very acceptable for me cause I need to get failure as soon as possible to not waste time.

Can I solve this situation somehow?

Thanks.

Comment: how do you trigger your installer build : do you have a main "parent" task in the root build project that triggers build of subprojects and the copy of all produced jars? and how did you create dependency between this task  and default build lifecycle task ?

Comment: @M.Ricciuti I am running `gradlew build` from root folder to trigger build for all subprojects. Then I have one of subproject called `installer` with `buildInstaller` task and instruction like `build.dependsOn buildInstaller`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create a `mustRunAfter` constraint on the `buildInstaller` task, to ensure it will be run after all subprojects `check` tasks:

In the *installer*  sub-project `build.gradle` :

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    rootProject.subprojects.each { Project subproj ->
        if (subproj.name != project.name) {
            buildInstaller.mustRunAfter subproj.getTasks().getByName('check')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this should not have impact on the parallel execution of subprojects tasks. did you try?

Comment: yeah, It works as you describe. But my expectations a little bit different. As I described in title, ideal situation would get tests running before artifact resolution. Then I can fail build as fast as possible. I think it reachable using `jar.dependsOn test` but I don't think that it's good pattern.